# Turn off latex/mathjax in spyder

Tags: matrix, scipy, spyder

So I ran the following code and for some reason spyder is presenting it in latex using some library it asked me to install rather than jsut reporting it as an array.

```
import numpy as np

from sympy import Matrix

b=2
m=np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, b, 1], [1, 0, 0], ])
A=Matrix(m)
T, R =A.jordan_form()
```

before it installed I called T

```
T
Out[9]: 
Matrix([
[ 0, -1, 0],
[ 1,  1, 1],
[-1,  0, 0]])
```

Now when I call T I get this annoying image in mathjax notation it looks ugly and I would rather jsut see the vlaues displayed as before
[image]

Comment: That image is from the console, I copied it over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To avoid that, you need to add the following code to your file:

```
import numpy as np

from sympy import init_printing, Matrix

init_printing(use_latex=False)

b=2
m=np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, b, 1], [1, 0, 0], ])
A=Matrix(m)
T, R =A.jordan_form()
```

You can do further adjustments to the way Sympy objects are printed by passing other options to [init_printing](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/interactive.html?highlight=init_printing#sympy.interactive.printing.init_printing).

Comment: Thank you so much,  I unfortunately uninstalled anaconda and now for some reason I can't import numpy ugghh I will try this once I get that bug fixed